# Why this _.every(...) returns false?

Tags: underscore.js

Can you explain why this statement returns **false**?

> _.every([true, 1, null, 'yes'], _.identity); // false

Without *null* it returns **true**. So this *null* is the problem. But `_.identity(null) === null` is **true**.

The example is from the official documentation (http://underscorejs.org/#every).

Comment: Hmm, you can look at the annotated source code for hints. My guess is it has to do with javascript truthy values.

Comment: My only hint is that it's said "Delegates to the native method *every*, if present." Maybe the native method screws it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `_.every` method will return true if and only if the iterator function returns a truthy value for every item in the array. `_.identity` is just a passthrough, so `_.identity(null)` will return `null`, which is not truthy. Iteration stops and `_.every` returns `false`.

Comment: Right, all _.identity does is return the argument.

Comment: Ah, I thought _.identity not only returns abut also checks if the value equals to itself.

Comment: Interestingly, if `_.identity` *did* check whether the value was equal to itself, I think `NaN` is the only value that would fail - so it would be equivalent to `isNaN`.